# How to generate fake book names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, faker

I am building a library management app in rails3.2. I am trying to generate book names for testing purposes. Is it possible to generate such book names using faker gem?

Comment: `Faker::Lorem.words(number_of_words)` ?

Comment: I'm assuming you just want to seed your DB? How about just using db/seeds.rb?

Comment: I am okay with Faker::Lorem.words(number_of_words). Thank you apneadiving and tattooedgeek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's post it as an answer:

```
Faker::Lorem.words(number_of_words)
```

adjust `number_of_words` to what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a book title using:

```
Faker::Book.title
```

you can also generate genre, publisher and author in the same way.

check Faker::book class [here](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/main/lib/faker/books/book.rb)